# POST multiple files and JSON to Web API

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, postman

This may sound naive. I am using Postman REST client to test below Web API.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Object value)
{
    //..
}
```

I can pass below JSON to API using POST and it works fine.

```
{
  "totalUsersOrganization": 0,
  "totalUsersBU": 0,
  "buid": null,
  "buName": "GIS",
  "toolTagMappingId": null,
  "tagName": "",
  "isReady": true,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "updatedOn": "2018-07-06T13:56:10.6711104+05:30",
  "updatedBy": null,
  "updatedByName": "",
  "rating": {
    "item1": 0,
    "item2": 0
  }
}
```

Now I need to POST three files along with the JSON to test my API. For that I tried using the same JSON as Form-Data in Postman as shown below.

[image]

When I POST it says invalid input. I tried setting/removing Content-Type but it did not work. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: I get- `InvalidDataException: Missing content-type boundary.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, int lengthLimit)` with 500 error code.

Comment: @Sid Something wrong in the Web API POST action?

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1